# Lista de objetos en Java

Tags: java, lista, poo

Se me pide hacer una lista de objetos, esta es mi clase principal

```
package listaObjetos;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ListaObjetos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Automovil> auto = new LinkedList<>(); 
    
        Automovil carro = new Automovil("Ferrari", "Rojo");
    
        auto.add(carro); 
 
        System.out.println(" " + auto.get(0));
```

Mi clase Automovil

```
class Automovil{
    private List<String> marcaLis;
    private List<String> colorLis;

    private String marca;
    private String color;

    public Automovil(String marca, String color){
        this.marca=marca;
        this.color=color;
    }
}
```

El problema es que al mandar a imprimir carro me devuelve el nombre del paquete:

```
listaObjetos.Automovil@15casfa12
```

Pero no me devuelve ningún error y **me debería de imprimir los datos que se ingresaron "ferrari" y "rojo"** . Si quito el get de la impresión y solo mando la lista me imprime el nombre del paquete.

No uso ArrayList porque no se me permite, tengo que usar List y LinkedList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la clase Automóvil deberías tener un método toString(), ya que en la parte en la que realizas un *System.out.println(" " + auto.get(0));*.El cual al imprimirlo debería usar el método toString el cual mostraría la información que tu le hayas añadido.

En tu caso al no tener puesto un método toString no imprime ninguna información del objeto, simplemente apunta a la dirección de memoria y poco mas.

Un ejemplo podría ser el siguiente:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Automovil{" +
                "marca='" + marca + '\'' +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

Comment: Si me faltaba eso, gracias.

Comment: Es buena práctica cada que sobrescribes el método toString añadir la anotación **@override**

Comment: lo tenia añadido, justo acabo de darle a editar y sinceramente no se porque no se ha mostrado, igualmente gracias por el recordatorio, así he podido darme cuenta de que no estaba añadido :)